# Remove user account in Android 5.0.1 on Galaxy S4

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, google-account, accounts

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android upgraded to 5.0.1. There is a GMail account added that I've linked in order to install a specific application (Google Domain Policy) and now I want to remove that account in order to pass the phone to my co-worker.

I've gone to `Settings` -> `Accounts` and the account is listed there (as a Google account). I can tap that and get to privacy and sync settings but I can't see any option to delete the account. I've tried tapping, tapping and holding, double-tapping, swiping and everything else that happened to cross my mind but to no avail.

How on earth do I remove that account from the system if there's no delete option visible?

[image: Settings -> Accounts]
[image: After clicking on "Google" account]

<sub>Click image(s) for larger versions</sub>

Comment: `/data/system/users/0/accounts.db` keeps the web accounts info. Remove the account entries from that file, restart and the account would be gone from Settings -> Accounts. This definitely needs root access.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I have spent weeks looking for a solution to this and finally this post helped me! It was so far from obvious and it felt like Google wanted me to keep the account by force lol.

Anyway, what I did was go to *Settings > Accounts > Google,* clicked the account I wanted to delete, the *Sync* menu option opened and this is where I always got stuck. Through this, I realized I had to press and hold the menu button on the bottom left side of my S4 to get another menu pop-up with the options of canceling sync or deleting the account.

Finally! Hope this helped.

Comment: Mine has no menu button. The following worked for me on a Galaxy Tab: 1st: Settings > Accounts > Google > Sync. 2nd: Disable all syncing. 3rd More > Remove Account.

Comment: Thank you this solve my problem.

Comment: Nice. But with latest 5.0.1 update, you must tap on bottom left button and not hold it.

Answer (score 23):

In order to remove an user account you need to perform:

1. Go to device **settings** (As shown in the question).
2. click on **accounts** Tab (3rd in the option list).
3. Click on **Google** Account (select the account which you wish to Remove).
4. First you need to **Stop Sync** (As done in question "synchr. wylaczonaa").
5. On Samsung devices these options are shown by pressing and holding the **Left** soft key beside home Button.(shown using red mark in image below).
6. Click on **Remove Account**.

[image]

I would suggest read the above steps and you are good to go.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLLwoZhqFVg

Comment: It didn't work exactly the same way as in your link but it pointed me in the right direction. I had to go to Settings -> Accounts, then tap the Google account, then press the 'menu' button at the bottom of the phone and only there I have found the 'delete account option'. Probably logical but totaly unintuitive, at least for me (I don't use Android, so I'm not used to its different quirks). In Android 4 on identical phone it was much, much easier. Thank you, anyway, you've pointed me to the solution.

Comment: This answer doesn't work.

Comment: Please explain the steps in detail, I've undeleted this since you seem willing to do so.  Thanks.

Comment: You have to single tap left button. Not press and hold!

Comment: Thanks, it save my life..

Answer (score 3):

Setttings- Accounts-Google- Tap the account you want to remove- it will open sync settings for that account- tap the bottom left touch button of your phone (out of three touch button in the bottom, the right one which resembles 3 horizontal parallal bars)- a menu will be appear (sync now and Remove account)- tap remove account.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried several times and finally found the solution with my s4 to remove the GMAIL account.

Settings --->
Accounts---->
Google------>
select the account need to be removed
it will be redirected to sync settings
click menu touch on bottom of the phone
select----> remove account

Answer (score 0):

This might help. You need touch on menu icon i.e in lower left corner to see sync now an remove  account.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=A5P67EFz92s

Comment: Might want to outline the steps in your answer in case the video becomes unavailable.

Answer (score -1):

I tried all of the above but nothing works, my phone doesnt have the menu button on the bottom so there was nothing to click on, but here is how i did it.

Settings > Accounts > Tap on Google > Search > Accounts and Privacy > Sign Out

very very cumbersome but finally figured it out! should have been easier than this.