# Remove user account in Android 5.1

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, google-account, accounts, zte-blade

I have a ZTE Blade L5 Plus with Android 5.1 that I was using for a while. Now I'm using a Samsung Galaxy phone. I want to remove the Google account from my old phone, so I can give it to a friend.

On the Samsung phone, I go to "Settings" then "Cloud and accounts" then "Accounts" then "Google" then I tap the Menu button (or vertical ellipsis⋮ - the three dots button) and I get two options: "Sync now" and "Remove account". So this is easy on Samsung.

But on ZTE, I go to "Settings" then on the third tab "Personal", I choose the third options "Accounts", then "Google" but here, if I tap the menu button, I only get the option "Sync now". In this screen I have the following three options:

- Sign-in & security
- Personal info & privacy
- Account preferences

If I go to "Account preferences", I have the option "Delete your Google Account" but that's for completely deleting my account, not for removing it from the telephone.

[This question already exists](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/111307/remove-user-account-in-android-5-0-1-on-galaxy-s4), but for a slightly different version of the OS: Android 5.0.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove user account in Android 5.0.1 on Galaxy S4](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/111307/remove-user-account-in-android-5-0-1-on-galaxy-s4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my phone, I went `settings`->`accounts`, selected `Google`. There I have two e-mails  registered, I clicked on the first one, and a set of details opens.

On this screen you see on the top right corner a menu, that allows you to remove the desired account. It didn't wipe my Google's account - if you are afraid, you could just put it on flight mode before taking these actions...

In your case, however, instead of just deleting the account, I would do a factory reset before selling my phone (even if it is to a friend, due to personal stuff I have in it, like pictures and *whatsapp* messages)

Comment: It works, indeed, thank you. Unlike Android 6 where you get the Remove option right as you enter into "Goolge", here you have to click the account first and only after that you get the "Remove account" when clicking the three dots menu button